# Azure Functions: Proxy + Deployment Slot + Querystring parameter

Tags: c#, azure-functions, api-gateway, azure-deployment-slots

I'm trying to implement a home-made "API gateway" for my Azure Functions using proxies to forward requests to different deployment slots depending on a query string parameter:

```
myapi.azurewebsites.net/customer/123?organizationId=1 ----> myapi-prod.azurewebsites.net/customer/123?organizationId=1
myapi.azurewebsites.net/customer/123?organizationId=2 ----> myapi-test.azurewebsites.net/customer/123?organizationId=2
```

And so on and so forth.

I've [RTFM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies) but I still can't figure out how to properly write the Route Templates to achieve this

**Q**: How can I configure function proxies for this scenario?

**Q2**: Is there a way to programatically declare these proxy configurations without writing a bunch of JSON, similar to `[FunctionName]` which allows me to declare my functions with a single attribute in my class?

Answer (score 1):

According to some test, azure function proxy doesn't support set the route template with query string like `?organizationId=1`. The route template can just be set as `customer/123/organizationId/1`. So you can set the proxies as below:

```
Route template: customer/123/organizationId/1 --> Backend URL: myapi-prod.azurewebsites.net/customer/123?organizationId=1

Route template: customer/123/organizationId/2 --> Backend URL: myapi-test.azurewebsites.net/customer/123?organizationId=2
```